# RemoveFromParent one of multiple node with same name after contact

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-engine

I got GameScene with mass similiar nodes. After my hero contact with one of that nodes (with same name and parameters), i need to remove node that he contact.

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {


    var firstBody = SKPhysicsBody()
    var secondBody = SKPhysicsBody()


    if contact.bodyA.node?.name == "redCircle" {

        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB}
    else {

        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA}

if firstBody.node?.name == "redCircle" && secondBody.node?.name == "indicatorBody" {

       candlesCounter = candlesCounter + 1
centerBody.removeFromParent()
    }}
```

This how i do it, but after contact, any random node is removed from the game scene. It is necessary to remove the one that contact the hero.

Comment: post your whole  ***didBeginContact*** method implemented code. you might doing it wrong

Comment: Here you go, buddy.

Comment: It is not random.... it is whatever you assigned centerBody to